# how to generate unique username based on user's fullname?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to generate unique username for every user during registration based on his/her name, user can change it later. If user entered 'smith doe' as his name in registration form, the auto generated username should be 'smith', but if 'smith' is already someone's username(u_name) then it should add any available number at the end of 'smith' : like- 'smith1' or 'smith2' or 'smith3' and so on...

Here is what i have tried :

```
$usnm  = $_POST['name'];    
$first_nut = explode(' ', $usnm);
$usnm3 = $first_nut[0];

$usnm5 = $usnm3;

function generateUsername($usnm3,$iteration = 0) 
{
$generated = $iteration > 0 ? ($usnm3 . $iteration) : $usnm3; //Increment username
$query_usnm = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (u_name = '$generated' or u_name = '$usnm3') ");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query_usnm) > 0) 
{
return generateUsername($usnm3,$iteration + 1);
}

return $generated;
 }

$usnm4 = generateUsername($usnm5);


$sql = mysqli_query($con, "insert into user (name, u_name) values ('$name', '$usnm4');");
```

Comment: What is the problem with your script?

Comment: @fusion3k it inserts same username multiple times, even if the username exists... It inserts 'smith' even if 'smith' is already someone's username

Comment: check the result of `$query_usnm`, because the problem is in it. The remaining code works for me. Side note: use ` SELECT * FROM user WHERE (u_name = '$generated') " ` (` or u_name = '$usnm3'` is unnecessary )

Comment: @fusion3k can you please suggest me how to do it ? I really need help bro...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to immediately get the `max(u_name)` from the table? If there is already a similar user then you get the highest one and can immediately increment it by one. Of course then you'd also have to adjust the `WHERE` clause to something like `WHERE u_name like 'smith%'` (to stick with your example).

Comment: I don't know your db structure. 1) put your query in a variable `$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (u_name = '$generated')"` , then print it ( `echo $query;` ) to see if it is right. If it is right, copy it and paste in phpmyqdmin to see if they are results.

Comment: @Ralph What about two user: `smith` and `smithson`  ?

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/36102882/5830574. The OP obviously has two accounts and now gets pushy because he did not like the comments on the other post.

Comment: @fusion3k Yes, you are right. I forgot about that. The where restriction would probably have to be adjusted a bit more. Maybe this could work: `where u_name = 'smith' or u_name like 'smith[000-999]%'`

Comment: @Ralph http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f65d/2 BTW your previous comment makes sense, if post-processed with `preg_grep`.